# RInno shiny app unable to launch if previous session closed unexpectedly

Tags: r, windows, shiny

I have made a Desktop shiny app for windows using the amazing package [**RInno**](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno) but I have been experiencing some inconsistencies with launching the application. Occasionally the application will not quit its session properly, leaving R running in the background. Their github suggests using this chunk of code in the server function to insure R is properly terminated when the session ends. I can tell when the application quits properly because I include a custom function that copies the log files to a new indexed name for records and debugging.

```
if (!interactive()) {
session$onSessionEnded(function() {
  write_logs_out() #My custom function. renames logs and stores backups of session data in .rds files
  stopApp()
  q("no")
 })
}
```

In these cases a new log file is not made so I assume `stopApp()` and `q("no")` are never executed as well, leaving R running in the background. One major issue is I do not know how to reproduce this error. My current guess is that this occurs when the R session locally becomes unresponsive. While R is still running in the background, the shiny app never fully opens to a web browser. I will first need to open task manager and quit any R sessions (usually with the name "R front-end") in order to get the app working again.

Since I dont know how to expect this random error, I was wondering if any windows experts could help me write a script that will check if an R process is running, and then kill it. This would at least

I know that

```
tasklist | findstr Rscript.exe
```

will list all the current Rscripts running (which I believe is the "R front-end" i see in task manager), but I don't know if it is bad practice to simply include `taskkill /IM "Rscript.exe" /F` before the line that calls the .wsf file that starts the app.

The main problem I see with this is that if the session is running fine and the user for some reason clicks the app again, it will force a complete restart.

Any suggestions?